# I deleted the network service of a usb ethernet adapter. How to get it back?

Tags: macbook-pro, network, usb, ethernet

I have a usb ethernet adapter that used to work just fine. Today I unplugged it, then deleted the corresponding network service via the dialog under "System Settings / Network".

Now when I plug the ethernet adapter back in, it does not work, even though the device still gets detected:

```
> system_profiler SPUSBDataType
        AX88179A:

          Product ID: 0x1790
          Vendor ID: 0x0b95  (ASIX Electronics Corporation)
          Version: 2.00
          Serial Number: 0000000000FBE2
          Speed: Up to 480 Mb/s
          Manufacturer: ASIX
          Location ID: 0x01100000 / 1
          Current Available (mA): 500
          Current Required (mA): 100
          Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

But no network service gets created for it. I also tried `networksetup -detectnewhardware` in the terminal, to no avail.

How can I make the device usable again?

System Info:

```
Hardware Overview:

  Model Name:   MacBook Air
  Model Identifier: Mac14,2
  Model Number: G15X5J/A
  Chip: Apple M2
  Total Number of Cores:    8 (4 performance and 4 efficiency)
  Memory:   24 GB
  System Firmware Version:  10151.61.4
  OS Loader Version:    10151.61.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried "Add Service" in the Network preference panel?

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit embarrassing, but it worked for this device. I had actually tried this before without success, but probably with a different usb ethernet device of the same kind. Will create a separate question for that issue, as I can still not add a service for that.